# Getting the value of a variable of another class

Tags: java, static, getter

```
public int getwidth() {

    return width;
}

public int gethight() {

    return hight;
}
```

I have this methods in another class. I need to use them in another class now to get this information. The problem is: even though (it seems to me) that it is not a static-context, it constantly tells me that it is a static context and so it doesn't work.

```
void setWidth()  {
     /* getterclass is the class where the getwidth method is in */
     this.width = getterClass.getwidth();
}
```

I tried it this way, but it doesn't work.

No matter what I do, it always tells me it is a static context.

It seems to me that I do a horrible mistake somewhere.

Comment: is `getterClass` the name of the class, or an instance of the class?

Comment: Sionnach733: Well, an instance. Isn't that somehow related? I mean name of the instance and the name of the class must be the same, right?

Comment: @DennisvonEich No, that is completely, utterly wrong. Instances can have any name that is a valid java identifier.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. A common convention is something like `GetterClass getterClass = new GetterClass();`. Class names usually start with an uppercase letter and instances start with lowercase

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Ehh, I mean not the instance itself, i mean the constructor. sorry

Comment: But the class getterClass is not just for the getter (just renamed it for translation). So the class has more than just the width and hight. Can I still use a whole instance to get the values of the variables of this class?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an instance of the class to call the method in a non-static context.  When you say class name-dot-method, that's attempting to call a static method.

You'll need to create and instance of the class or accept one as a parameter.

```
void setWidth()
{
    GetterClass instance = new GetterClass();
    this.width = instance.getwidth();
}
```

or

```
void setWidth(GetterClass instance)
{
    this.width = instance.getwidth();
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by "attempting to call a static method". I mean after all it is not a static method so why do they tell me that it is?

Comment: Because "class name-dot-method" is the syntax for calling a static method, whereas "instance variable name-dot-method" is the syntax for calling an instance (non-static) method.

Answer (score 1):

`getterClass.function()` are static functions, function of the class, you need to create a instance first to use it properly

```
getterClass variable = new getterClass(); //variable.width initialized in constructor?
this.width=variable.getwidth();
```

or pass the instance like parameter

```
public void setWidth(getterClass variable){
this.width=variable.getwidth();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `getWidth()` as a static method, by calling it using just the class name and not using an instance of the class. You should either change `public int getWidth()` to `public static int getWidth()`, or make an instance of the class getterClass and use that to call the method.